# reg ex for anything after a specific character and between others

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the file name of the string `attachment; filename="contract.pdf"`

How can I always extract what's in between the quotes (e.g. contract.pdf)? Or maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input = "attachment; filename=\"contract.pdf\"";
var filename = input.match(/\battachment;\sfilename="([^"]*)"/);
alert(filename[1]);
```

See fiddle demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/texnq303/)**.